# How to reload same activity with giving data with intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Below is my code, but I dont get `restaurant_id` ,after reload activity;

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RestaurantDetailActivity.class);
refresh.putExtra("restaurant_id", mDataset.get(position).getRestaurantId());
startActivity(refresh);
finish();
```

Comment: when you reload Activity, you have lost that data which is coming from the back activity.

Comment: What do you mean by `RELOAD` here ? Please explain your problem .

Comment: you can try doing with onResume and checking if restaurant id has value or not...

Comment: why can't you try this https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html means recreate activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following steps...

1. Refresh `RestaurantDetailActivity`

   ```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantDetailActivity.this, RestaurantDetailActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("restaurant_id", mDataset.get(position).getRestaurantId());
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    RestaurantDetailActivity.this.finish();
   ```
2. In `OnCreate()` you should do like this in the same activity

   ```
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int restaurantId = extras.getInt("restaurant_id");
        // todo with restaurantId
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try this

- Use intent in your same activity like this

  ```
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle.putExtra("restaurant_id", 
                   list.get(position).getRestaurantId());
                   intent.putExtras(bundle);
                   startActivity(intent);
  ```
- loadData() use in your onCreate method in same activity like this

  ```
    private void loadData() {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    final String restaurantId = bundle.getString("restaurantId ");
    }
  ```
- You can use OnResume Method in your activity
- You can define a function that loads your data for Activity and call it in onResume().
- loadData method call onCreate method and onResume method

  ```
       @Override
       public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();

        loadData();

       if (restaurant_id.equals(null)){

              //write your code here
         }else{

       //write your code here
        }
  ```